# UIButton action not called inside custom view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a custom view, that will contain the following:

- a green view
- inside the green view an image view
- on top of this another white view
- another image view on top of the white view
- and on top of all an UIButton

This is my code which is inside a custom view:

```
func setup() {

    // add green view
    let greenView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
    greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    greenView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(greenView)

    // add first image
    let image1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
    image1.image = UIImage(named: "checked2")
    image1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    greenView.addSubview(image1)

    // add white image
    let whiteView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
    whiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    whiteView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    greenView.addSubview(whiteView)

    // add second image
    let image2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
    image2.image = UIImage(named: "checked")
    image2.userInteractionEnabled = true
    whiteView.addSubview(image2)

    // add button
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("animation:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(button)



}

func animation(button: UIButton) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

The button, which is red appears on top, but the action is not called when clicking on it.
I tried to set `userInteractionEnabled` on all of the elements, but with no effect.

Comment: Make sure that user interaction is enabled for that custom view.

Comment: In the console do you see an error that says something like: can't find selector?

Comment: I don't get any message. The custom view has userInteractionEnabled set to true

Comment: It seems auto layout was the problem. After clearing the constraints for the custom view container, its working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code which you have posted is working fine, the problem is with the container view which holds all your views, maybe `userInteractionEnabled` is false for the container view.

Comment: The custom view container also has userInteractionEnabled set to true

Comment: ok, it seems to be working now. I cleared the constraints for the custom view container and now its working. So auto layout was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Button user Interaction is on by default, no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: no need to declare it in class, view also has reference to it (after adding as subview) so it won't get released

Comment: addSubview will add views and hold a strong reference to them and won't get released

Comment: Then simply the button interaction is blocked of any other view.